# Prevent Material-UI Autocomplete Popper component from being absolutely positioned

Tags: css, reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

So the problem is that I need `Material-Ui autocomplete` not to be absolutely positioned so it can take whatever height and width it needs. `disablePortal` prop helps in some ways because it stops the popper from moving in scenarios that the space is not enough to contain the popper component.

Look at below picture to see one of the problems it makes:

[image: unpleasant popper]

In the above picture, for example I want to have a border around the box containing the `Autocomplete`, as the `Popper` component is absolutely positioned, it's not achievable. if you choose several items then again the height changes and it makes it even harder:

[image]